# PHP MYSQL: search word query

Tags: php, mysql, search, tags

i need to submit a query to search posts with a specific tag. the cell in the database is written this way : "funny tech good" so every word describe a tag. so i have writed this code in order to get a posts with the "funny" tag.

```
'SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `post_tag` = "funny" ORDER BY `post_id` DESC LIMIT 50'
```

unfortunately , it gives me no result. what is the problem in here?

Comment: you could try WHERE post_tag LIKE 'funny%' .. which will show your records having 'funny' as starting text in your tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `LIKE` keyword or store your tags in a 1-tag-per-entry fashion.

```
 SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `post_tag` LIKE "%funny%" ORDER BY `post_id` DESC LIMIT 50
```

This will however find tags, that have other tags included, so a search for "java" will also find "javascript",

Answer (score 1):

The query `WHERE post_tag LIKE  "%fun%"` will also match "funny", "defunct", etc. But you're in luck, because MySQL also supports perl-style regular expressions and you can say

```
WHERE post_tag RLIKE "\bfun\b"
```

(Be sure the sql engine sees the backslashes). This will only match "fun" as a complete word.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `post_tag` LIKE  "%funny%" ORDER BY `post_id` DESC LIMIT 50'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `post_tag` LIKE "%funny%" ORDER BY `post_id` DESC LIMIT 50'

//OR to get tags starting with funny
'SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `post_tag` LIKE "funny%" ORDER BY `post_id` DESC LIMIT 50'
```

Ref: [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)